# Wordpress Staging site is redirecting to live and lost the child theme

Tags: redirect, child-theme, staging

I had a staging version for a WordPress site that contained a child theme as the main one, and everything was working well. After a few weeks, the staging site suddenly keeps redirecting to the live version and the child theme is not showing in the theme's appearance section anymore.

This all happened without any modifications. Any idea why it happened and how to fix it?

Comment: Have you checked your wp_options table to see if the paths were renamed to your live URL? I'd scan the db first for traces of that live path.

Comment: @cstls Is there a specific column that I should check? There are thousands of cases.

Comment: Right. The main thing is to take a look and check that that is actually the reason your site is being redirected. If this is true, then take a look here. You're going to need to find and replace any instances of columns containing your live URL with the staging URL you want to replace it with. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29697144/change-site-url-and-wordpress-url-in-localhost

Comment: Can I change them from the dashboard or should I have access to the db?

Comment: You'll need access to your db via phpMyAdmin or the like.

Comment: Thanks! Any idea why the child theme was removed?

Comment: Not sure, have you looked in the /themes folder on this dev server to ensure it's still there?

Comment: Yes, it is. The weird thing is that links in the dashboard are redirecting to the live version as well.

Comment: With the hosting platform you're using, did you pull down the latest db from live to dev? Something like this would explain the redirects. My guess is the fix is find/replace in the db.